# Is there a term for a Venus visibility period

Tags: terminology, venus

Is there a term for the period of time when Venus is first visible in the evening to when it switches to being the "morning star", or vice versa?  For example, as depicted in the image below, from Early Oct 2022 to late July 2023, Venus will be visible in the evening.

I know the Mayans took a particular interest in the 8 different patterns produced (for where they were), but never found a word they used for the patterns, nor the time periods they represent.  I'm not looking for a Mayan word specifically, just anything other than "the time when Venus is visible in the evening/morning this time around".

[image: Venus path]
[Code to produce image above](https://github.com/gmiller123456/Venus-After-Sunset-Chart)

Comment: Evening apparition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the most common word used for this is "apparition".

I just saw this mentioned in Meeus' "Mathematical Astronomy Morsels IV", and searching for the term, it seems pretty common.

Answer (score 2):

The closest term is probably "elongation".  When Venus is visible in the evening it is an Eastern Elongation.  (It is East of the sun, but in the Western sky in the evening)

However it doesn't refer to the time period as much as the angular distance from the sun, so one speaks of "maximum elongation".

However you do hear terms like "a favourable elongation" (when the planet is easily visible) but more often when refering to Mercury.

Comment: +1 QQ: Does "elongation" applies for the moon or moons of other planets?

Comment: Yes, . The Moon's elongation is its angular distance east of the Sun at any time.  It could also be used of other planets, but I dont think it is used of moons of other planets